# Php unit test fail with post request

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I am trying to do unit test with  symfony 5.1 and php unit version 7.5.20, php version 7.4.3
But this fails for post request
error `X-Debug-Exception` `The parameter 406 must be defined`

```
Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Exception\InvalidArgumentException: The parameter "406" must be defined.
```

Sample code which i have tried

```
public function testCreatePost()
{
    $client = static::createClient();
    $client->request(
        'POST',
        '/api/install',
        [],
        [],
        [
            'CONTENT_TYPE' => 'application/json',
            'HTTP_ACCEPT' => 'application/json',
            'HTTP_HOST'       => '192.168.1.2',
            'SERVER_NAME'       => '192.168.1.2',
            'HTTP_SERVER_PORT' => 8085,
            'HTTP_USER_AGENT' => 'MySuperBrowser/1.0',
        ],
        '{}'
    );

   // $request = $client->getRequest();
    $response = $client->getResponse();
    dump($response);
    exit;
    $this->assertEquals(200, $client->getResponse()->getStatusCode());
```

Comment: What happens if you go to the endpoint in your test normally?

Comment: The same error occurs if change the mode to test in api calls

Comment: So does that mean the problem is not with the test, but with the actual endpoint? If so, maybe you could put up some code of the controller action

Comment: @mickadoo Thanks for your response .. I have fixed the issue by adding auto_generate_proxy_classes: false this in my doctrine config for test env